# Does a circle minimize mean squared curvature in the plane?

Tags: geometry, optimization, curvature

Suppose we have a non-intersecting closed curve in the plane of fixed length 1 with continuous second derivative. Its mean squared curvature is
$$\langle \kappa \rangle = \int_C |\kappa|^2 ds = \int_0^1 \left|\frac{d^2 \textbf{x}(s)}{ds^2}\right|^2 ds,$$
where the curve is parameterized by arclength.

Does the circle with circumference 1 minimize this quantity over all twice continuously differentiable closed curves?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the circle do minimize the integral of curvature squared.

Recall the [total absolute curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_absolute_curvature) of any closed curve is at least $2\pi$.
For any closed curve of length $1$, we have

$$\int_0^1 |\kappa(s)|ds \ge 2\pi$$
By Cauchy Schwarz, this leads to
$$\int_0^1 |\kappa(s)|^2 ds = \left(\int_0^1 |\kappa(s)|^2 ds\right)\left(\int_0^1 ds\right) \ge \left(\int_0^1 |\kappa(s)| ds \right)^2 \ge (2\pi)^2$$
Since a circle of unit circumference has constant curvature $2\pi$, its
integral of curvature squared takes the smallest possible value $(2\pi)^2$.